# show progress when httprequest in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I've created (using plunkers from other SO users) a feature where users can search for a movie title which causes the app to do a httprequest to themoviedb.org and serve all results in a list. By using a promise all the images are served at once dodging the waterfall effect and also it shows a "loading" update while the images are getting for being served to the browser.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y01giYN9E3g92KjVEkua?p=preview

Pretty great. But it's not enough! I want to show the users the progress of their search action. My prefered method would be show a progress bar that fills up during the httprequest but I'm having trouble getting started.

This is my controller:

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("main", ["moviesearchFactory", "$scope", "$q",  function(moviesearchFactory, $scope, $q) {

    $scope.createList = function(searchquery) {
      $scope.loading = true;
      moviesearchFactory.getMovies(searchquery)
        .then(function(response) {

          $scope.movies = response;
          $scope.images = [];

          $scope.movies.forEach(function(movie) {
            if (movie.poster_path !== null) {
              $scope.images.push({ poster_path: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2/' + movie.poster_path , 
              title: movie.title })
            }
          });

          function preLoad() {

            var promises = [];

            function loadImage(src) {
              return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = src;
                image.onload = function() {
                  resolve(image);
                };
              })
            }

            $scope.images.forEach(function(image) {
              promises.push(loadImage(image.poster_path));
            })


            return $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
              $scope.imagesLoaded = $scope.images;
              $scope.loading = false;
            });
          }

          preLoad();

        })
    }
  }])
```

How would I go about adding a progress bar to this controller?

Comment: Have you looked at http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/?

Comment: Myea I did see it but didn't like : `increments the loading bar by a random amount.` to me it sounds like the loading doesn't respond to the actual request. Or is this a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 1):

I've created two plunks that may help you. Check them out here.

1. http://plnkr.co/edit/vKACEbYrwbpENyIOua8x?p=preview

```
$scope.createList = function(searchquery) {
      $scope.showProgress= true;

<md-progress-circular class="" ng-show="showProgress"
                        md-diameter="100px"></md-progress-circular>
```

2. http://plnkr.co/edit/1P3mpR61XOuMPON7IDce?p=preview

Comment: Yea the second plunkr looks great. It's just a feature in Angular Material? Why did you add Angular Messages by the way? (Thanks for the help).

Comment: Its angular material,you can go to https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressLinear, if you want you can use bootstrap, go to http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp ,I think you can remove angular message